# (github) Started getting "permission denied (publickey)". Fixed it… should I take further steps?

Tags: security, github, ssh

There are a bunch of "I'm getting 'permission denied' on git/ssh actions, what do I do" questions, where the answer is generate a key if necessary, add it to the agent, and associate it with your Github/Bitbucket/etc account. I'm all set with that… my question is do I need to worry about getting "permission denied" errors in the first place? Are there any measures I need to take to address some problem that happened?

Here's the story: I was happily going along, working on a long-standing projects I'm the owner of on Github… and then I couldn't push. I got (via SourceTree) a string of "permission denied (public key)" errors, over and over. So I started debugging:

`ls ~/.ssh` shows `github_rsa`, `github_rsa.pub`, `id_rsa`, and `id_rsa.pub`. `ssh-add -l [-E md5]` both gave me `The agent has no identities.`

`ssh -vT git@github.com` gave me (this is OSX 10.11)

```
...
debug1: identity file /Users/---/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/---/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/---/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/---/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/---/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/---/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/---/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/---/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
...
Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
Found key in /Users/---/.ssh/known_hosts:1
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/---/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/---/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/---/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/---/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and adding `id_rsa.pub` as a new Github key fixed it.

But the fact that I had a problem in the first place seems worrisome right? I could connect fine yesterday. Was I compromised in some way? Should I do anything more, or just be happy that I can connect again?

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, you probably had `github_rsa` in your `ssh-agent` and it got removed somehow? Doing

- `ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa`

or

- putting `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa` to your `~/.ssh/config`

should solve your issue even with removed `id_rsa.pub` from your github account.

But you should be good with using the `id_rsa`, unless it is some file you have no idea how it appeared in your computer. In that case, you should not use that and go back to the old one or generate new one (if you computer was physically compromised).

Comment: That makes sense about `github_rsa`, and now that you say it I'm not sure why I didn't go with that one. So your sense is I don't need to worry about the "it got removed somehow" part? In the time between things working and things not working, my computer was asleep and locked in a house with no one else home. _Something_ must have happened _somewhere_